# How to add file to django model form with onetonefield to User

Tags: django

Is there any reason why uploading image file does not work .I have posted this question several times .I will need help for some one to show me the best code practice to upload image file .

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be the user who uploads the file, then you can do something like this in your view.

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_file = form.save(commit=False)
    new_file.user = request.user
    new_file.save()
```

Comment: after that is done , how can i   successfully upload an imagefile using the djangomodelform